# I spoke to a patent attorney about an idea with a drawing.

Tags: design-patent

He professed it wasn't worth anything and that it would be too costly to bring to market (this was maybe 7yrs ago).  It is now showing a patent pending and is being marketed through several sources.  The price I suggested and the name of the idea is the same as I discussed with the attorney.  How can I research this further?

Comment: Have you managed to find out if the guy stole your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry of consulting a new attorney, you could:

- see who filled the application
- see who is listed as an inventor
- see if they have any affiliation with that earlier attorney